# Wordpress: If User Role = CSS-Class THEN Display: none

Tags: wordpress

I have a (hopefully small) problem for a customers project with user specific content. I need a function that adds `".user-role { display: none !important; }"` into the inline-css to make sure that specific user roles cannot see specific html objects. So if the users role is "abc-user" there must be `".abc-user { display: none !important; }"`

Is that possible or is there a better solution to solve this problem? As the website works with visual composer (unfortunately) it is nearly impossible to work with shortcodes because complete rows shall be not visible for users.

I'm looking forward to your answers! :)

Best regards from Germany,
Max

Comment: I hope you're not doing this for anything resembling security reasons, since the DOM elements will be perfectly visible to anyone who cares to inspect the page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution for anyone who is maybe interested.
Thank you @Aki for your help!

```
add_action('wp_head', 'hidingCss');
function hidingCss() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $role = (array) $user->roles;
        { 
            //.abc-user is a class which you are targeting for hide any element
            echo '<style>.'.$role[0].' { display: none !important; }</style>';
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using into functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'hidingCss');
function hidingCss() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $role = (array) $user->roles;
        //csss-class means user roles
        if($role[0] == 'CSS-Class'){ 
            //.abc-user is a class which you are targeting for hide any element
            echo '<style>.abc-user { display: none !important; }</style>';  
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aki! Thank you very much!
Unfortunately the code is not working for me. There is no output in the source-code (and i think _abc-user_ must be replaced by _$role_ doesn't it?).

Comment: I changed the code now to `add_action('wp_head', 'hidingCss');
function hidingCss() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
     $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
  {
            echo '<style>.$role { display: none !important; }</style>';  
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}`

but unfortunately i have now an output with `<style>.$role { display: none !important; }</style>`... How can i solve that there stands "admin" or "author" or "abc-user" instead of $role? It seems like the variable is not working correctly?

Comment: You removed code of if condition which actually checking the user capability. check my new code and read the comments

Answer (score 0):

While checking the role may be the ideal solution here, oftentimes, checking the capability is favorable. It allows a simpler and more robust approach to managing the things a user can and cannot do on a site.

If we only want a single role to be able to use or see the functionality, definitely use either of the solutions presented above. If however, you need all users with a certain capability - say the ability to upload_files, (which includes the roles: author, editor and admin) you might try something like this instead.

```
function hidingCss() {
  if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('upload_files')) {
    echo '<style>.abc-user { display: none !important; }</style>';
  } 
 }

 add_action('wp_head', 'hidingCss');`
```

In this way, every role with the ability to upload_files will have this bit of css echoed in the header rather than a single role.

Obviously we can create our own roles with our own capabilities to extend this even further and make it even more powerful.

- More on roles and capabilities:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
- More on current_user_can:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can
- Standard roles and capabilities at a glance:
  https://exygy.com/wordpress-roles-and-capabilities-at-a-glance/
- Great tutorial on the subject:
  https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-user-roles/